# I am having issue in my if condition. Based on user selection day It has to validated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the Day and timing from the user. Here is how do I do that in javascript. Using jquery hide and show I am showing the timing form. Further I want to validate the form, based on user selection.
My questions are:

Based on the users selection I want to validate the day and timing:

1. If select monday. It has to validate only monday From Time and To Time then form has to submit. It should validate enter tuesday from time.
2. Like wise If user select both monday and tuesday It has to validated both.and form has to submit

http://jsfiddle.net/kodesh/kog3ugbt/1/

Here is my form:

```
<form name="f1" action="s.php" method="post">
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="color:#999; font-size:14px; text-align:right;">What times are you generally available to take classes?</p>
            </td>
            <td style="color:#999; font-size:14px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" class="day" value="monday" />
                Monday 
                <span class="times-monday hidden" id="day">
                    Timing
                    <select name="mondayfromtime" id="mfrom">
                        <option value="">----Start Time-----</option>
                        <option value="Monday 6:00 am">6:00 am</option>
                        <option value="Monday 7:00 am">7:00 am</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="mondaytotime" id="mto" >
                        <option value="">----End Time-----</option>
                        <option value="TO 6:00 am">6:00 am</option>
                        <option value="TO 7:00 am">7:00 am</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" class="day" value="tuesday" />
                Tuesday
                <span class="times-tuesday hidden" id="day1">Timing
                    <select name="tuesdayfromtime" id="tfrom"  >
                        <option value="">----Start Time-----</option>
                        <option value="Tuesday 6:00 am">6:00 am</option>
                        <option value="Tuesday 7:00 am">7:00 am</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="tuesdaytotime" id="tto" >
                       <option value="">----End Time-----</option>
                       <option value="TO 6:00 am">6:00 am</option>
                       <option value="TO 7:00 am">7:00 am</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
                <br/>
                <Tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="validation" />
                    </td>
                </Tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.day', function() {
        $('.times-' + this.value).toggle();
    });
    $('#day').hide();
    $('#day1').hide();
    $('#day2').hide();
    $('#day3').hide();
    $('#day4').hide();
    $('#day5').hide();
    $('#day6').hide();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByName("f1")[0].onsubmit = function() {
        var day = document.getElementsByName('day[]'),
            dayOk = false;
        for (var i = 0, n = day.length; i < n; i++) {
            if (day[i].checked) {
                dayOk = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!dayOk) {
            alert('please select the Day');
            day[0].focus(); // focus the first
            return false;
        }
        mform = document.getElementById('mfrom');
        mto = document.getElementById('mto');
        if (mform.value == '') {
            alert('enter the monday  From Timing');
            mform.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (mto.value == '') {
            alert('enter the  monday To  Timing');
            mto.focus();
            return false;
        }

        tform = document.getElementById('tfrom');
        tto = document.getElementById('tto');
        if (tform.value == '') {
            alert('enter the Tuesday  From Timing');
            tform.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (tto.value == '') {
            alert('enter the Tuesday To  Timing');
            tto.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true; // allow submit
    }
}
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementsByName("f1")[0].onsubmit = function() {
            var day = document.getElementsByName('day[]'),
                dayOk = false;
            for (var i = 0, n = day.length; i < n; i++) {
                if (day[i].checked) {
                    dayOk = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!dayOk) {
                alert('please select the Day');
                day[0].focus(); // focus the first
                return false;
            }
            mform = document.getElementById('mfrom');
            mto = document.getElementById('mto');
            if (mform.value == '') {
                alert('enter the monday  From Timing');
                mform.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (mto.value == '') {
                alert('enter the  monday To  Timing');
                mto.focus();
                return false;
            }

            tform = document.getElementById('tfrom');
            tto = document.getElementById('tto');
            if (tform.value == '') {
                alert('enter the Tuesday  From Timing');
                tform.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (tto.value == '') {
                alert('enter the Tuesday To  Timing');
                tto.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true; // allow submit
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: See my comments: https://gist.github.com/sukima/1cb2d3a8f2b9a44f4f4e (Not an answer but a code review critique.)

Comment: My sincere thanks you and your valuable guidelines.You got  my concept . I am sure I will  do this. can give the solution for this. if user click monday I am  showing the timing using jquery show and hide.I am comfortable with javascript so using document.getElementById('mform') mform is nothing but monday from time. I am validation. I follow you word.can you work with this in jquery. Already I spent three days to this work Unable to complete this.It is annoying .Finally I believe stackteam .Please excute with your idea. I hope You got the concept clearly

Comment: I don't understand why your using jQuery in one part and avoiding it in the next.

Comment: I do it this way: http://jsbin.com/taqege/1/edit